# Arxiv - Undefined citations and references, even using previously-functional files

Tags: natbib, arxiv

I've been trying to re-upload an updated version of a paper on arxiv. I upload the .tex and .bbl files, and run several times but am always unable to compile, every single citation and reference (i.e. equation and figure label reference) is flagged up with

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Hall:2010jx' on page 1 undefined on input line 224.
```

and

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:conclusions' on page 2 undefined on input line 262.
```

etc.

I've even tried  ***using the original files*** which did compile (by pressing the 'bring previous version forward' button on the file upload page) and they no longer do! Something has changed in the last few months but I'm clueless on how to adjust to it.

I've tried all the solutions I can find on stackexchange, but nothing works. I'm uploading the .bbl file, I'm using `\include{XXX.bbl}`, I've put `\pdfoutput=1` at the top. Everything compiles fine in TeXstudio with just the .tex and .bbl files in the folder.

Would really appreciate help if anyone has any ideas.